# using sqlite3 with nodejs without npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

I'm running nodejs on a Windows with just node.exe (no npm). currently i'm wanting to hook nodejs up to sqlite3 in a way that doesnt require any additional modules now i have found one way that is dependent on the [sqlite3.exe](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html) (the command line interface for sqlite3) and [nodejs child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) and that looks like this.

```
var seperators=['##','$$'];
var spawn=require('child_process').spawn;
module.exports=function(file){
    if(!file){
        file="main.db";
    }
    var db=spawn(__dirname+'/sqlite3.exe',[file],{cwd:__dirname,stdio:["pipe","pipe","pipe"]});
    var database={};
    var resolvers=[];
    db.stdin.write('.separator '+seperators[0]+' '+seperators[1]+' \n');
    db.stdout.on('data',function(data){
        data=new Buffer(data);
        data=data.toString('utf8');
        data=data.split(/\r\n/);
        if(data[data.length-1]===''){
            data.pop();
        }
        for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
            if(resolvers.length>0){
                var current=resolvers.splice(0,1)[0];
                if(current[2]){
                    data[i]=database.parse(data[i]);
                }
                current[0](data[i]);
            }else{
                console.log(data);
            }
        }
    });
    db.stderr.on('data',function(data){
        data=new Buffer(data);
        data=data.toString('utf8');
        data=data.split(/\r\n/);
        if(data[data.length-1]===''){
            data.pop();
        }
        for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
            if(resolvers.length>0){
                console.log(data[i]);
                var current=resolvers.splice(0,1)[0];
                current[1](data[i]);
            }else{
                console.log(data);
            }
        }
    })
    database.tables=[];
    database.getTables=function(){
        var promise=new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
            db.stdio[0].write(".tables \n");
            resolvers.push([resolve,reject,false]);
        });
        return promise;
    };
    database.getTables().then(function(data){
        data=data.split(/\s+/);
        if(data[data.length-1]===''){
            data.pop();
        }
        database.tables=data;
    });
    database.read=function(table){
        var promise=new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
            db.stdio[0].write("select * from "+table+";\n");
            resolvers.push([resolve,reject,true]);
        });
        return promise;
    };
    database.read('tbl1').then(function(data){
        data=data.split(/\|/);
        if(data[data.length-1]===''){
            data.pop();
        }
        for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
            data[i]=data[i].split(/,/);
        }
        database.testing=data;
        console.log(data);
    });
    database.store=function(data,table){
        if(typeof data==="object"){

        }
    };
    database.parse=function(data){
        data=data.split(seperators[1]);
        for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
            data[i]=data[i].split(seperators[0]);
        }
    };
    return database;
};
```

at least that is what i have so far. my worry about this is that im not sure if sqlite3.exe returns processes in the same order with which they were called. If it does return them in order then this works fine but otherwise im not sure where to go from here. does anyone know if this will have significant problems? Is this bad practice?

Also I know what sql injection is and I will be taking steps to prevent it please do not include sql injection in any of your answers I'm already working on that its not part of the question I want answered.

Comment: Using the sqlite3 shell as a database API is unnecessarily complex; you lose prepared statements and query parameters (essential for safe queries), need to parse the output, and introduces the overhead of another process.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo  Okay do you know of any other options

Comment: Use the library bindings. Or make your own.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo as I said I can't use npm so no library. And I don't know c or c++ so I can't really make my own. Although I could learn I'd prefer a JavaScript solution

Comment: There isn't a pure Javascript solution. The SQLite API is in C, so you will need to write C bindings in order to use the SQLite library as intended.

Comment: So aside from having to parse the results are there any other major downfalls of using the shell? I mean it's just like typing code into the command line and many of the commands are the same as they would be in the library (I have looked over the library). It takes more initial code for me to type up but after that I don't see any difference in functionality. Overhead should be the same because it's the same as if I loaded the library.

Comment: Prepared statements and query parameters could be programmed in because prepared statements are just strings and I could use a for loop to have it iterate trough adding different variables to the string. And query parameters are accessible from the command line so it can be typed in through stdin

Comment: Do you know how SQL injection works? Do you know how query parameters solve it? And prepared statements are not "just strings".

Comment: Prepared statements are just strings from the JavaScript end. And sql injection isn't one of my worries because I'm not connecting the database directly to the web and unescaped strings won't be able to make it through my JavaScript code at least by the time I'm done. Plus this is still just experimental I'm not putting it into production

Comment: Sql injection especially isn't a worry because I was going to pull the table names from getTables so I know when it tries to read a table that the table actually exists and the query parameters will be predefined as well so it won't be running any of the users searches in there.

Comment: "unescaped strings won't be able to make it through" That's not saying much; no one intentionally writes vulnerable code unless they are ignorant, malicious, or proving a point. Your proposed solution to SQL injection ("checking the table names") doesn't make sense; how would checking which tables the query is operating on prevent, for example, `"DELETE FROM users WHERE id = " + "1 OR 1"`?

Comment: Look at the function getTables it returns an array of all the tables in the database so if somehow a request for table information goes through and he table doesn't exist because they have the malicious code in there it won't ever try to request the table I'll stop it before it reaches the database

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107328/discussion-between-colonel-thirty-two-and-binvention).

Comment: You asked `does anyone know if this will have significant problems? Is this bad practice?`.  The answer to both of these is **yes!**.

Comment: @dsh why is it bad practice? What significant problems are you referring to? And since you think so do you know of a good alternative? Just yes doesn't help or clarify much